# Hiding the second Jquery selection

Tags: jquery

How can I hide the second selection if the first selection had not been made yet. This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#select1").change(function() { 
            if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
                /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
                $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
            } 

            var id = $(this).val();
            var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');

            $('#select2').html(options);
        });
    });

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <select name="select1" id="select1">
            <option value="3"></option>
            <option value="1">IT</option>
            <option value="2">Management</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select2" id="select2">
            <option value="3"></option>
            <option value="1">Programmer</option>
            <option value="1">Technician</option>
            <option value="2">HR</option>
            <option value="2">Secretary</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/jrst4qg8/

**JS:-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#select1").change(function() { 
            if(this.value != 3){
                $("#select2").show();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#select2").hide();
            }
            if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
                /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
                $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
            } 

            var id = $(this).val();
            var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');

            $('#select2').html(options);
        });
    });
```

**CSS:-**

```
#select2 { display:none }
```

Comment: I just want to hide the data in the selection. Not the selection bar

Comment: @Najwa You mean empty drop-down initially. And show values after selection in select2. right? http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/jrst4qg8/1/

Comment: Accept your answer?I don't understand.I'm new in here

Comment: @Najwa You will see right check mark unfilled next to my answer near vote button, click on that to accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hide by default the second selection with css and show it when you select something from `#select1`

CSS:

```
#select2 { display:none }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '#select1', function() {
    $('#select2').show();
    // ....
});
```

Comment: Where should I put the css?Sorry I'm just a beginner

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CSS for initial display i.e., second dropdown should be hidden by default.

**CSS Code:**

```
#select2 {
            display: none;
}
```

Though you can hide the second dropdown by using jquery, it is not recommended as when ever the page loads at first HTML will be loaded along with the css properties and then js files.

**jQuery Code:**

```
$("#select2").hide();
```

Then, you need to show / hide the second dropdown using jQuery based on the option selected in the first dropdown.

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(this).val() != 3 ? $("#select2").show() : $("#select2").hide();
```

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p21denLh/)**